# Is this program compatible on both big and little endian systems?

Tags: c, endianness

I wrote a small program which reverses a string and prints it to screen:

```
void ReverseString(char *String)
{
    char *Begin = String;
    char *End = String + strlen(String) - 1;
    char TempChar = '\0';

    while (Begin < End) 
    {
        TempChar = *Begin;
        *Begin = *End;
        *End = TempChar;
        Begin++;
        End--;
    }
    printf("%s",String);
}
```

It works perfectly in Dev C++ on Windows (little endian).
But I have a sudden doubt of its efficiency. If you look at this line:

```
while (Begin < End)
```

I am comparing the address of the beginning and end. Is this the correct way?
Does this code work on a big endian OS like Mac OS X ?
Or am I thinking the wrong way ?

I have got several doubts which I mentioned above.
Can anyone please clarify ?

Comment: As a minor nit-pick, there's no point in having TempChar outside the loop, and also no point in initializing it. Move it inside the loop, and make it const: const TempChar = *Begin;.

Comment: Another minor nitpick - Mac OS X is not big endian, it can be either big or little endian as it runs on x86 (little endian), PowerPC (big endian) and other architectures.

Comment: If you're looking for issues, this code has undefined behavior when passed an empty string located at the start of an array - it's not valid to take a "one before the beginning" pointer. In practice it will work anywhere with a flat memory model, and probably most places without.

Answer (score 7):

Your code has no endianness-related issues. There's also nothing wrong with the way you're comparing the two pointers. In short, your code's fine.

Comment: can you explain me it in detail about why do u think that its correct?

Comment: @Zombie: There are only pointers and characters (bytes) in your code. The bytes are by definition endian-neutral. And all you do with the pointers is read, assign, increment and decrement, all of which are endian-neutral operations. You're dereferencing bytes which is also endian-neutral. So everything's fine.

Answer (score 4):

Endianness is defined as the order of significance of the bytes in a multi-byte primitive type. So if your `int` is big-endian, that means the first byte (i.e. the one with the lowest address) of an `int` in memory contains the most significant bits of the `int`, and so on to the last/least significant. That's *all* it means. When we say a system is big-endian, that generally means that all of its pointer and arithmetic types are big-endian, although there are some odd special cases out there. Endian-ness doesn't affect pointer arithmetic or comparison, or the order in which strings are stored in memory.

Your code does not use any multi-byte primitive types[*], so endian-ness is irrelevant. In general, endian-ness only becomes relevant if you somehow access the individual bytes of such an object (for example by casting a pointer to `unsigned char*`, writing the memory to a file or over the network, and the like).

Supposing a caller did something like this:

```
int x = 0x00010203; // assuming sizeof(int) == 4 and CHAR_BIT == 8
ReverseString((char *)&x);
```

Then *their* code would be endian-dependent. On a big-endian system, they would pass you an empty string, since the first byte would be 0, so your code would leave `x` unchanged. On a little-endian system they would pass you a three-byte string, since the first three bytes would be `0x03`, `0x02`, `0x01` and the fourth byte 0, so your code would change `x` to `0x00030201`

[*] well, the pointers are multi-byte, on OSX and on pretty much every C implementation. But you don't inspect their storage representations, you just use them as values, so there's no opportunity for behavior to differ according to endianness.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, endianness does not affect a char * as each character is a single byte and forms an array of characters. Have a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html?ca=drs-
The effect will be seen in multi byte data types like int.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you manipulate whole `type T` objects (which is what you do with `type T` being `char`) you just can't run into endianness problems.

You could run into them if you for example tried to manipulate separate bytes within a larger type (an `int` for example) but you don't do anything like that. This is why endianness problems are impossible in your code, period.